# SAPUI5 Fragment won't open

Tags: javascript, html, fragment, sapui5

I am trying to make a popup/fragment in SAPUI5 that shows comments listed in a database. I know the database works fine along with the calls. When i click on the button that is supposed to open the fragment, nothing happens.

## Controller.js

```
_getDialog: function() {
        // associate controller with the fragment
        this.oCommentDialog = sap.ui.xmlfragment("really.long.destination.fragment.CommentDialog", this);
        this.getView().addDependent(this.oCommentDialog);

        // toggle compact style
        jQuery.sap.syncStyleClass("sapUiSizeCompact", this.getView(), this.oCommentDialog);

        //this.oCommentDialog.open;
        return this.oCommentDialog;
    },

    onCommentDialogPress: function(oEvent) {
        var oCommentDialog = this._getDialog();
        console.log(oCommentDialog);
        oCommentDialog.open();
    }
```

## CommentDialog.fragment.xml

```
<core:FragmentDefinition
xmlns="sap.m"
xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">
<Popover
    title="Comments"
    class="sapUiContentPadding"
    placement="Top">
    <footer>
        <Toolbar>
            <ToolbarSpacer/>
            <Button
                id="email"
                text="Email"
                press="handleEmailPress" />
        </Toolbar>
    </footer>
</Popover>
```

[image: Here is the error i get in the console.]

**Uncaught TypeError: oCommentDialog.open is not a function**

The line above the error from `console.log(oCommentDialog);` has a return function or prototype.
So i know this is working, or at least i think.

I HAVE ALREADY CHECKED TO SEE IF OPEN() IS SET TO SOMETHING ELSE IN CODE, and it is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a `Popover`, which does not have an `open` method.
If you want to open a `Popover` you need to use the [`myPopover.openBy(control)`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Popover.html#openBy).

You can find the documentation [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Popover.html)

The fact that you are trying to use `open`, and considering your variable name, it looks like you might be looking for the [Dialog](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Dialog.html) control.

Comment: That helped! thank you very much for the clarification!